# How to intercept GetById in cypress?

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress

I am currently intercepting a Get api in cypress and it works fine:

```
cy.intercept('GET','/api/products', {
    body: list,
});
```

Now I want to be able to intercept the GetById - I tried the below but it does not work, it still considers the code above which is a get all:

```
cy.intercept('GET','/api/products/1234', {
    body: list,
});
```

Is there a way to intercept urls with parameters in cypress?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the issue, I had to update to cypress 7.0.1. In the latest version of cypress, the url are more strictly checked.